# Why use a blank @Document for MongoDB domain objects?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have seen a lot of code defining domain objects for MongoDB in the following fashion:

with a blank @Document annotation:

```
@Document
class Customer {
 int id;
 String name;
}
```

without the `@Document` annotation:

```
class Customer {
 int id;
 String name;
}
```

with a collection name:

```
@Document(collection = "cust")
class Customer {
 int id;
 String name;
}
```

I can understand the last two, **but why would you want to keep just the `@Document` annotation ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring Documentation states:

7.3. Metadata based Mapping

> To take full advantage of the object mapping functionality inside the
> Spring Data/MongoDB support, you should annotate your mapped objects
> with the @org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document
> annotation. Although it is not necessary for the mapping framework to
> have this annotation (your POJOs will be mapped correctly, even
> without any annotations), it allows the classpath scanner to find and
> pre-process your domain objects to extract the necessary metadata. If
> you don't use this annotation, your application will take a slight
> performance hit the first time you store a domain object because the
> mapping framework needs to build up its internal metadata model so it
> knows about the properties of your domain object and how to persist
> them.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-document/docs/current/reference/html/